# How To Get More Detailed Pardot Form Handler Error Messages

Tags: pardot

I'm currently submitting my form to a pardot form handler endpoint. I have set a URL for when submission fails and the redirection works well. The issue is that, pardot form handler is not really explicit in its error messages. It only sends something like **Please correct the following errors:~~~ - This field is required~~~** with no further details. So my question is how to get pardot form handler to send me more detailed or explicit error messages when the submission fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the advanced tab in the field setup UI will provide an input to provide your own, more descriptive error message.

[screenshot of Pardot API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zB5Y.png)